# Sonos API Redirect URI with external controller

Tags: sonos

I would to know how to create Redirect URI if I want to control with the external control instead of application or web.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "external control", I guess you mean something like a hardware controller? In that case, you'd have to have some kind of app or web site to set up the hardware controller. You'd use this app to execute the Sonos authentication, and in this case, the redirect uri would be handled by that app or web site.